# Problemas con Archivo en C

Tags: c, archivo

Buenas tardes! Tengo el siguiente codigo en C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define tamString 100

void            
cargarArchivo(FILE * archivo, char phrase[tamString]);

int
main()
{
    FILE    *archi;
    archi = fopen("archis.txt", "w+b");
    char    frase[tamString];

    puts("Ingrese una frase");
    fgets(frase, tamString, stdin);


    cargarArchivo(archi, freis);

    fclose(archi);

    return 0;
}

void
cargarArchivo(FILE * archivo, char phrase[tamString])
{

    char     resultado[tamString];
    int      i = 0;
    long int maxLenght = 0;

    fwrite(phrase, sizeof(char), sizeof(phrase), archivo);

    maxLenght = ftell(archivo);
    rewind(archivo);

    fread(resultado, sizeof(char), sizeof(resultado), archivo);

    for (i = 0; i < maxLenght; ++i)
    printf("%c", resultado[i]);

}
```

El problema es cuando quiero mostrar por pantalla el resultado de fread(), me muestra solo 8 o 9 caracteres, no todos los demas.

Comment: has probado a volcar la salida con `printf("%s",resultado);`???

Comment: Sería cortés de tu parte (y buena práctica para tu futuro academico/profesional) formatear el código (indentados) y agregar comentarios. Sobre todo con el "contrato" de la funcion (qué se supone que hace)

Comment: Si en lugar de obligarnos a adivinar qué intención tiene cada linea de tu código lo hubieras comentado, por ejemplo, sabríamos si to fwrite() hace lo que pretende hacer. Pareciera que no. No deberías usar `sizeof` en ese caso. `sizeof` es un keyword que se resuelve en tiempo de compilacion y te da el tamaño de la variable (en este caso, el tamaño del array alocado, no el tamaño del string

Answer (score 2):

Luego de darle un poco de cabeza a tu código, mas lo que dice leonboy y todos los que comentaron, he modificado un poco tu código utilizando `#include <string.h>` para comprobar el tamaño con `strlen()` y el resultado es el que esperas, no se si es parte de un ejercicio que andas realizando, por lo que no sé si es válido usar `strlen`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define tamString 100

void cargarArchivo(FILE * archivo, char phrase[tamString])
{
    char     resultado[tamString];
    int      i = 0;
    long int maxLength = strlen(phrase);

    fwrite(phrase, sizeof(char), maxLength, archivo);

    rewind(archivo);
    fread(resultado, sizeof(char), sizeof(resultado), archivo);

    for (i = 0; i < maxLength; ++i)
        printf("%c", resultado[i]);

}
```

Actualmente el problema de tu código se encuentra aquí:

```
fwrite(phrase, sizeof(char), sizeof(phrase), archivo);
```

La razón es que `sizeof(phrase)` siempre dará 8 o 4 como resultado debido a que `sizeof` solo devuelve la cantidad de bytes necesarios para posicionar una variable en memoria, no importa la longitud del archivo, siempre será 8 o 4.

[Pregunta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619914/why-is-char-str-anything-always-the-size-of-8)
[Referencia a ftell](http://c.conclase.net/librerias/?ansifun=ftell)
[Referencia a fread](http://c.conclase.net/librerias/?ansifun=fread#inicio)

Espero te haya ayudado.